# Keep two different databases synchronized

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, etl

I'm modeling a new microservice architecture migrating some part of a monolithic software to microservices.

I'm adding a new PostgreSQL database and the idea is in the future use that database but for now I still need to keep updated the old SQL Server database and also synchronize the PostgreSQL database if something new appears in the old database.

[image]

I've searched for ETL tools but are meant to move data to a datawarehouse (that's not what I need). I just can't replicate the information because the DB model is not the same.

Basically I need a way to  detect new rows inserted in the SQL Server database, transform that information and insert it in my PostgreSQL.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you tell us more information about whence the database inserts are occurring?  Might it be possible to have the insert calls duplicate to cover the other database?

Comment: The main software is going to use the AWS Lambda I'm creating so yes, It's possible to have the inserts calls duplicate, but some other part of the system will also hit the SQL Server to insert or update, so I need to check if some new rows are inserted in the DB also.

Comment: Do you need this to be real time, in the sense that you must minimize the chances that the two database are ever out of sync?

Comment: Basically a POST HTTP call will execute the AWS Lambda and it will save the entity to one or both databases (this depends on me). But as some other parts of the system are not going to use my new microservice for now, I need a way to keep both databases syncronized. 
If it's needed, I can use any existing AWS tool to solve this.

Comment: It should be real time or at least minimize the chances that the two databases are out of sync.

Comment: An ETL tool **is** what you are looking for. They are not only intended for populating a data ware house. They are intended to do exactly that: extract the data from somewhere, transform it to something different load it somewhere else. But they are usually not intended for "real time" replication.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was thinking to use AWS Glue (ETL) and save the changes in an S3, then use a lambda to pick this files and populate the DB.. what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at StreamSets Data Collector.  It can detect changes in SQL Server and insert/update/delete to any DB that has a JDBC driver including Postgres. It is open source but you can buy support. You can also make field changes/additions/removals/renaming to the data stream so that the fields match the target table.

Answer (score 0):

[PostgreSQL's foreign data wrappers](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers) might be useful. My approach would be, to change the frontend to use PostgreSQL and let postgreSQL handle the split via it's various features (triggers, rules, ...)